# Joomla Hit module CSS

Tags: joomla, count, hit

So I am using this module for a Joomla website: 
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/analytics/visitors/20925

And I was wondering how do I edit the CSS of it?
It is putting a border around the module and I also want to get rid of the "Created by" text.
I can't seem to find a CSS file to edit anywhere.
Would appreciate any help thanks!

Comment: You can't see the CSS with Firebug?

Comment: I used Firebug to check but it doesn't say the file name unless I'm missing something? it says text/css but I can't find that. Can you use Firebug to show you the full directory path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be looking for the following which is located in **default.php** on line **29**

```
.hitcounter_container {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

and remove `border: 1px solid #DADADA;` from it.

As for removing the "Created by" text, please ensure you are allowed to remove it before I answer how to.

Comment: I deleted the border thing but it completely broke the website for some reason :S

Also, I don't see anything that says you have to keep the created by text there.

Comment: you did remove the whole line didn't you? This would not break the whole website. Maybe you removed an extra semicolon or forgot to remove it.

Comment: I did remove the whole line, but for some reason when I was saving the file it was adding in weird stuff and was breaking the file, no idea why it happened.
I had to download the file from Filezilla and make the changes and reupload it to fix the problem! Thanks for the help!